# With given k, find the geometric sum using recursion

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class GeometricSumFromK {


    public static int geometricSum(int k,int a)
    {

        if(k == 0)

            return 1;

        a = a*2;
        return 1/a + geometricSum(k-1, a);

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter k");
        int k = s.nextInt();
        int a = 1;
        System.out.println(geometricSum(k,a));


    }

}
```

How can I, with a given k, find the geometric Sum e.g. 1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + ... + 1/(2^k) using recursion
For now, it is showing 1 for every value of k.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do several things wrong:

- the method should return a double not an int
- when you do 1/a and you do not explicitly cast it to float/double the default result will be an int (this is the default type of a arithmetic operation in java between integral operands, if not explicitly cast to something else). That means it takes the integral part of the result (which in this case is always 0 since 1 is always less than whatever value has a). which means the result 1 is because of the case when you explicitly return 1.

You should do something like this

```
public static float geometricSum(int k,int a)
{

    if(k == 0)

        return 1;

    a = a*2;
    return ((float)1/a) + geometricSum(k-1, a);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, do you really want an `int` as a return value? I think you should be asking for `double`. Secondly, everytime you execute `1/a`, when *a* is `int`, the value gets rounded down, for example 1/2 isn't 0.5, but 0. This is why you eventually ends up with 1.

This should work:

```
public static double geometricSum(int k,int a)
{

    if(k == 0)

        return 1;

    a = a*2;
    return (double)1/a + geometricSum(k-1, a);

}
```

This part: `(double)1/a` ensures that the result is a `double`.

Comment: You could also just do `1.0/a`.

Comment: i tried to do it using double but still the answer was the same

Comment: i was storing the value of 1/a + geometricSum(k-1,a) in a variable double p and then i was returning p
but still my answer was the same.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public static float geometricSum(float k,float a)
    {

        if(k == 0)

            return 1;

        a = a*2;
        return 1/a + geometricSum(k-1, a);

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter k");
        float k = s.nextFloat();
        float a = 1;
        System.out.println(geometricSum(k,a));


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

this code will work fine in all cases

```
double geometricSum(int k) {


    if(k==0)
    return 1;

    int ans=pow(2,k);
    return ((double)1/ans)+geometricSum(k-1);

}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public class GeometricSum {

    public static double findGeometricSum(int k) {

        double temp = 0, num = 0;

        if (k == 0) {
            return 1;
        }
        for (int i = 1; i <= k; i++){
            num += (1) / (Math.pow(2, i));
            temp = num;
        }
        return temp + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) Please properly indent your code. 2) Your algorithm does not compute a geometric sum. 3) And most important: your algorithm is not using recursion as OP explicitly requested!